C# Get (alive) references to instance?
I have an application, where the user can create Expressions through the ui. This Expressions, he can assign to almost every property of every object-instance throughout the whole application.
Expressions can be properties, or can be contained in lists / dicts, if something requires multiple expressions.
Now, i'm thinking of building a UI-Part that quickly outlines where a expression is used. i.e. something like:
Expression: 
"$variable1 > 100"

Usage: 
Instance55 of Class C in property "OutOfBoundsExpression"
Instance2 of Class B in property "IsWaterBoilingExpression"

I could manually track this, sure - but I wonder if there is a builtin way to query for this? My thoughts are wandering around the GarbageCollector, it should be pretty well aware of what object is used wherr?
Something like
Expression instance; //received through whatever way.
Dictionary<Object, List<PropertyInfo>> usages =
     System.GarbageCollector.GetReferences(instance);


As of the comments, it seems a bit unclear, what I want to achieve. So, heres a code example, how I would achieve that manually:
Basically I would modify each Property-Setter to register the assignment in a dictionary:
Code Structure:
static Dictionary<Object, Dictionary<MemberInfo, List<Expression>>> ExpressionAssignments 
      = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<Object, Dictionary<MemberInfo, List<Expression>>>();

public class ClassA
{
    private Expression _CurrentValueExpression;
    private List<Expression> _VisibleExpressions;

    public List<Expression> VisibleExpressions { get
        {
            return _VisibleExpressions;
        } 
    }

    public Expression CurrentValueExpression
    {
        get
        {
            return _CurrentValueExpression;
        }
        set
        {
            _CurrentValueExpression = value;

            //leaving out key-exists-checks
            //single expressions would always hava a single item assigned, index 0. 
            ExpressionAssignments[this][CodeUtils.GetMemberInfo(() => this.CurrentValueExpression)][0] = value;
        }
    }

    public void AddVisibleExpression(Expression ex)
    {
        this._VisibleExpressions.Add(ex);
        //leaving out key-exists-checks
        //List / Array / Dict Members can reference multiple Expressions
        ExpressionAssignments[this][CodeUtils.GetMemberInfo(() => this.VisibleExpressions)].Add(ex);
    }
}

Or something similiar. Now, I could use the Dict to figure out the usage of any Expression, something like:
ClassA instance1 = new ClassA()
 {
     CurrentValueExpression = new Expression("$MyLovelyVariableName")
 };

 ClassA instance2 = new ClassA()
 {
     CurrentValueExpression = new Expression("$MyLovelyVariableName")
 };

 instance1.AddVisibleExpression(new Expression("$AnotherVariable == true"));

 //.....
 foreach (var instance in ExpressionAssignments)
 {
     foreach (var mapping in instance.Value)
     {
         foreach (Expression expression in mapping.Value)
         {
             Log.I("Instance " + instance.ToString() + " is referencing Expression " + expression.ToString() + " through Member: " + mapping.Key.Name);
         }
     }
 }

would yield the information:

Instance instance1 is referencing Expression $MyLovelyVariableName
through Member: CurrentValueExpression


Instance instance1 is referencing Expression $AnotherVariable == true
through Member: VisibleExpressions


Instance instance2 is referencing Expression $MyLovelyVariableName
through Member: CurrentValueExpression

(Example does not distinguish between reference and content-equality of the Expression Object, equals-operation just uses the expression string itself)
Now, as you can imagine: This requires a lot of property-setter, list-adder (and therefore list-remover, list-clearer, list-exchanger...) to be modified - while exactly THIS information is one of the fundamentals of the Garbage-Collector to figure out which Objects have become orphans without references.
Hence, the question if that information can be retrieved from GarbageCollector to avoid re-inventing the wheel.

I’m sorry, I’m not getting it. Can you explain a little about what you’re trying to accomplish overall, or show us how you would “manually track this” if you had to? That might help clarify the problem.

You may be interested in some runtime diagnostics. ClrMD will let you attach to a running process, or create a dump and inspect it.

@JohnWu I've added a code example on how I (maybe) would do this manually, usage and expected results.

No, short of attaching a debugger, there is no way to get this information out of dotnet's GC. Strictly speaking, GC is an implementation detail. It lets our programs run as if they had infinite available memory. It may be finding references by consulting the oracle in Delphi for all we should care. Also, being an implementation detail, there are all sorts of messy details about it which would complicate using it in the manner you intend. E.g. there are GC roots on the stack, GC roots in lifted lambda closures, iterator and async method state machines, and who knows what else may appear eventually. All these would have to be distinguished from references which are covered by your desired semantics.
As for implementing your semantics, it is a natural use case for AOP, either in the form of a source generator (like ones created to emit INotifyPropertyChanged boilerplate) or a weaver which modifies the compiled assembly. The former approach is simpler, as it does not involve manipulation of compiled code, but suffers from odd-looking source code (e.g. declaring only backing fields and letting the code generator generate corresponding properties). Personally I prefer the latter approach and am the author of a compiled templates library, but using it correctly is non-trivial.
